# writing a file to a fat16 file system

Tags: c++, file-upload, copy, fwrite, fat16

So, I recently adapted this code I found online, which is a command line tool that copies a file in a FAT16 file system, and puts it into your 'regular;' directory:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mount.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>



typedef struct {
    unsigned char first_byte;
    unsigned char start_chs[3];
    unsigned char partition_type;
    unsigned char end_chs[3];
    unsigned long start_sector;
    unsigned long length_sectors;
} __attribute((packed)) PartitionTable;

typedef struct {
    unsigned char jmp[3];
    char oem[8];
    unsigned short sector_size;
    unsigned char sectors_per_cluster;
    unsigned short reserved_sectors;
    unsigned char number_of_fats;
    unsigned short root_dir_entries;
    unsigned short total_sectors_short; // if zero, later field is used
    unsigned char media_descriptor;
    unsigned short fat_size_sectors;
    unsigned short sectors_per_track;
    unsigned short number_of_heads;
    unsigned long hidden_sectors;
    unsigned long total_sectors_long;

    unsigned char drive_number;
    unsigned char current_head;
    unsigned char boot_signature;
    unsigned long volume_id;
    char volume_label[11];
    char fs_type[8];
    char boot_code[448];
    unsigned short boot_sector_signature;
} __attribute((packed)) Fat16BootSector;

typedef struct {
    unsigned char filename[8];
    unsigned char ext[3];
    unsigned char attributes;
    unsigned char reserved[10];
    unsigned short modify_time;
    unsigned short modify_date;
    unsigned short starting_cluster;
    unsigned long file_size;
} __attribute((packed)) Fat16Entry;







void fat_read_file(FILE * in, FILE * out,
                   unsigned long fat_start, 
                   unsigned long data_start, 
                   unsigned long cluster_size, 
                   unsigned short cluster, 
                   unsigned long file_size) {
    unsigned char buffer[4096];
    size_t bytes_read, bytes_to_read,
           file_left = file_size, cluster_left = cluster_size;

    // Go to first data cluster
    fseek(in, data_start + cluster_size * (cluster-2), SEEK_SET);

    // Read until we run out of file or clusters
    while(file_left > 0 && cluster != 0xFFFF) {
        bytes_to_read = sizeof(buffer);

        // don't read past the file or cluster end
        if(bytes_to_read > file_left)
            bytes_to_read = file_left;
        if(bytes_to_read > cluster_left)
            bytes_to_read = cluster_left;

        // read data from cluster, write to file
        bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, bytes_to_read, in);
        fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, out);
        printf("Copied %d bytes\n", bytes_read);

        // decrease byte counters for current cluster and whole file
        cluster_left -= bytes_read;
        file_left -= bytes_read;

        // if we have read the whole cluster, read next cluster # from FAT
        if(cluster_left == 0) {
            fseek(in, fat_start + cluster*2, SEEK_SET);
            fread(&cluster, 2, 1, in);

            printf("End of cluster reached, next cluster %d\n", cluster);

            fseek(in, data_start + cluster_size * (cluster-2), SEEK_SET);
            cluster_left = cluster_size; // reset cluster byte counter
        }
    }
}
void  parse(char *line, char **argv)
{
  while (*line != '\0') {//until the end of the line... 
    while (*line == ' ' || *line == '\t' || *line == '\n')//...while the character in memory is any of these...
      *line++ = '\0'; //...replace it with a 0.     
    *argv++ = line;//change the given argument to the changed line.           
          while (*line != '\0' && *line != '\t' && *line != '\n' && *line != ' ')//while the line is not at one of these symbols...

        line++;//...skip the argument            
     }
  *argv = '\0'; //mark the end of the argument list        
  printf("%s\n", line);      
}

int reader(char *b[]) {
    FILE *in, *out;
    in = fopen(b[1], "rb");
    int i, j;
    unsigned long fat_start, root_start, data_start;
    PartitionTable pt[4];
    Fat16BootSector bs;
    Fat16Entry entry;
char filename[9] = "        ", file_ext[4] = "   "; // initially pad with spaces

 if(sizeof(b) < 4) {
printf("Usage: read_file <fs_image> <FILE.EXT>\n");
return 0;
}
if((in = fopen(b[1], "rb")) == NULL) {
printf("Filesystem image file %s not found!\n", b[1]);
return -1;
}
    // Copy filename and extension to space-padded search strings
for(i=0; i<8 && b[2][i] != '.' && b[2][i] != 0; i++)
filename[i] = b[2][i];
for(j=1; j<=3 && b[2][i+j] != 0; j++)
file_ext[j-1] = b[2][i+j];
printf("Opened %s, looking for [%s.%s]\n", b[1], filename, file_ext);





    fseek(in, 0x000, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&bs, sizeof(Fat16BootSector), 1, in);

    // Calculate start offsets of FAT, root directory and data
    fat_start = ftell(in) + (bs.reserved_sectors-1) * bs.sector_size;
    root_start = fat_start + bs.fat_size_sectors * bs.number_of_fats *
        bs.sector_size;
    data_start = root_start + bs.root_dir_entries * sizeof(Fat16Entry);

    printf("FAT start at %08X, root dir at %08X, data at %08X\n", 
           fat_start, root_start, data_start);

    fseek(in, root_start, SEEK_SET);

    for(i=0; i<bs.root_dir_entries; i++) {
        fread(&entry, sizeof(entry), 1, in);
if(memcmp(entry.filename, filename, 8) == 0 && 
  memcmp(entry.ext, file_ext, 3) == 0) {
            printf("File found!\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    if(i == bs.root_dir_entries) {
        printf("File not found!");
        return -1;
    }

    out = fopen(b[3], "wb"); // write the file contents to disk
    fat_read_file(in, out, fat_start, data_start, bs.sectors_per_cluster * bs.sector_size, entry.starting_cluster, entry.file_size);
    fclose(out);

    fclose(in);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
  char line[1024];
  char *ag[64];
  while(1){
    printf(":/>");
    gets(line);
    parse(line, ag);
    if (strcmp(ag[0], "exit")==0)
      exit(0);
    if (strcmp(ag[0], "cpout")==0){
      char* b1[4];
      b1[1]=argv[1];
      b1[2]=ag[1];
      b1[3]=ag[2];
      int i=reader(b1);
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to do now is have a command that takes a file from your regular directory, copies it, and puts that copy in the FAT16.  Does anyone have an inkling of how that might be done?

Comment: Why don't you use the `mount` command and then just `cp` the file?

Comment: @Diego because I want this to be all in one command line program.  I am also a masochist.

Comment: Then use the `mount` syscall hehe... Now seriusly, you will need write support (the code you posted only reads from FAT16). Maybe you could borrow from some OS fs implementation, like Linux or some BSD.

Comment: @Diego would fat_write_file be similar to the fat_read_file function?

Comment: No, I don't think so. For writing you need to update the root directory to add a file (and maybe handle the complete file hierarchy), find some free clusters, link them somehow and associate them to the new file, finally write the data. I don't know the details of how FAT works, though.